# Get distinct, sorted list from column of lists in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table that looks like the following:

```
Field1,Field2
AAAA,111;222
AAAA,222;333
AAAA,333;444
BBBB,999;000
```

How can I make this one row only as a list of ascending values?

```
Field1,Field2
AAAA,111;222;333;444
BBBB,000;999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (field1, field2) as
  2  (select 'AAAA', '111;222' from dual union all
  3   select 'AAAA', '222;333' from dual union all
  4   select 'AAAA', '333;444' from dual union all
  5   select 'BBBB', '999;000' from dual
  6  ),
```

First split `field2` into rows; `distinct` will eliminate duplicates; then aggregate them back using `listagg`:

```
  7  temp as
  8    (select distinct
  9       field1,
 10       regexp_substr(field2, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) f2
 11     from test cross join
 12       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                           connect by level <= regexp_count(field2, ';') + 1
 14                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15    )
 16  select field1,
 17         listagg(f2, ';') within group (order by f2) field2
 18  from temp
 19  group by field1;

FIEL FIELD2
---- ------------------------------
AAAA 111;222;333;444
BBBB 000;999

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to have a temp/with statement? I tried doing a listagg over the regex but it doesn't work well. If there's any way to get it in the same SQL that would be ideal, if not perhaps you know why.

Comment: CTE isn't *evil*. That's just another sort of a subquery. I'd suggest you to run query that begins at line #7 (add WITH keyword first, i.e. WITH TEMP AS ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple (fast) string functions (rather than slow regular expressions) using:

```sql
WITH split_fields (field1, field2, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT field1, field2, 1, INSTR(field2, ';', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT field1, field2, epos + 1, INSTR(field2, ';', epos + 1)
  FROM   split_fields
  WHERE  epos > 0
),
items (field1, item) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         field1,
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(field2, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(field2, spos, epos - spos)
         END
  FROM   split_fields
)
SELECT field1,
       LISTAGG(item, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item) AS field2
FROM   items
GROUP BY field1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Field1, Field2) AS
SELECT 'AAAA', '111;222' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAAA', '222;333' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAAA', '333;444' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBBB', '999;000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | AAAA | 111;222;333;444 |
> | BBBB | 000;999 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4be8620d39c96abe1ccb1d64185837ad)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to break apart the FIELD2 values, then put them back together with LISTAGG:

```
WITH cteSubfields
  AS (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(FIELD2, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS SUBFIELD
        FROM TEST_TABLE
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(FIELD2, ';')+1)
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1,
                LISTAGG(SUBFIELD, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1) AS FIELD2
  FROM cteSubfields
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=53ff88eb17023937b87d5abff5992142)

Comment: This is going to have huge performance issues on large lists (or large numbers of rows) as the hierarchical query will generate exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate values (because the hierarchical query is not correlated within the row so will be joined to ALL prior rows in the hierarchy). Yes, `DISTINCT` removes them but that creates a lot of work in generating and then removing the duplicates. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=76bc47f6ca10ffcf70f0d04cbac4d86c) where adding 2 rows with 9 items each means you suddenly generate almost 10,000 duplicates.